# Настройка memchashed на vps (файл sock ложиться в другой каталог)

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, memcached

Друзья!
В конфиге указал указал каталог для создания файла `-s /tmp/memcached.sock`
При запуске сервиса memcached он создает папку внутри tmp[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы файл ложился ровно в /tmp/ ?

Comment: Не нужно класть сокеты в /tmp, для этого существует /run

Comment: Было бы не плохо, но он не запускается если указать другую папку (

Comment: Читайте логи и выясняйте почему не запускается

Comment: Спасибо за совет! решил проблему закомментировав строчку PrivateTmp=true в файле /lib/systemd/system/memcached.service. Но файл оставил в /tmp/

Почему нужно размещать его в run?

Comment: Потому что: во-первых, /tmp может редактироваться любым пользователем и какой-нибудь злоумышленник (если он попал в систему) из другого приложения может на место memcached.sock подсунуть свой вредоносный сокет; во-вторых, потому что сам здравый смысл подсказывает, что /tmp существует для временных файлов, а не для сокетов; в-третьих, потому что существует /run специально для этого и нет никаких объективных причин использовать какую-то другую папку

Comment: В-четвёртых, ваша строка автоматически раскомментируется обратно при ближайшем обновлении системы, потому что вы отредактировали файл, который находится под управлением системного пакетного менеджера. Вам бы подучить основы линукса в целом и systemd в частности

Comment: Я переместил юнит memcached.service в папку /etc/systemd/system/

Что скажете?